# How to bind ComboBox to ObservableCollection property?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, binding, combobox

I want to bind a ObservableCollections's string property to a ComboBox.

**Model**:

```
class Sequence : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public Sequence() { }

    private int _id;
    public int ID
    {
        get
        {
            return _id;
        }
        set
        {
            _id = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("ID");
        }
    }
    private string _name;
    public string Name
    {
        get
        {
            return _name;
        }
        set
        {
            _name = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("Name");
        }
    }

public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
        protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
        {
            PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }
}
```

**Viewmodel:**

```
private ObservableCollection<Sequence> _storedSequences = new ObservableCollection<Sequence>() { };
    public ObservableCollection<Sequence> StoredSequences { get { return _storedSequences; } }
```

**View XAML:**

```
<ComboBox x:Name="sequencesComboBox" SelectedIndex="0" ItemsSource="{Binding StoredSequences}" DisplayMemberPath="{Binding Name}" >
```

The problem is that the ComboBox does not show the string property. See the following picture (NQR_GUI_WPF is the namespace):

[image]

**Can someone please tell me what I'm doing wrong?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unless you want some special template, you don't need to set the `ItemTemplate` on your `ComboBox`.  You've already bound to your `ItemSource`, so to set the display member path, you just give it the string name of the property:

```
<ComboBox x:Name="sequencesComboBox" 
          SelectedIndex="0" 
          ItemsSource="{Binding StoredSequences}"
          DisplayMemberPath="Name" >
```

If you said it was kind of awkward it behaves this way I wouldn't disagree.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need binding in DisplayMemberName. Remove binding from DisplayMemberPath

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify the `DataTemplate` of the item.

```
<ComboBox x:Name="sequencesComboBox" SelectedIndex="0" ItemsSource="{Binding StoredSequences}">
   <ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}"/>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
</ComboBox>
```